# how to enable sorting in gridview after change header text

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview

I have a gridview in my web page to show my query result

I wrote necessary function to sort by clicking on column's title

but when i change title in code behind i can't sort by clicking

how can i change column format from text to hyperlink after binded data  ?

Comment: I think you have mention anywhere title in sorting...

Comment: i recommend you stop torturing yourself and start using jQuery/ajax/ & webmethods/webservices

Comment: Can you add some code.. to rectify the issue

Answer (score 3):

I already faced this "error" too. Trick is to avoid converting Header to string, when you changing it's Text value (you are probably using e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "This is changed header 1" in your code behind). After this all changed columns will be with disabled sorting. So, you need to treat header not as text, but as LinkButton and everything will be perfect.

This is my solution :

I am using OnRowDataBound="Exmplgrid_RowDataBound" in my grid definition. If you will use this, sorting will stay enabled on first 3 columns and disabled in 4th (for demo purposes):

```
protected void Exmplgrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            LinkButton btnSort = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0];
            btnSort.Text = "This is changed header 1";
            btnSort = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[1].Controls[0];
            btnSort.Text = "This is changed header 2";
            btnSort = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[2].Controls[0];
            btnSort.Text = "This is changed header 2";
            e.Row.Cells[3].Text = "This is changed header 2. SORTING DISABLED"
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`In order to provide a better answer please release some codes for fix!`

Working with grid views in web pages are a bit tough but some experts release out controls which you can use for developing a web site or a web app you can have look at following link and even evaluate other controls like WYSIWYG Editor, scheduler,tree view,Menus and more on Telerik Asp.net controls.

[Grid - Programmatic Sorting](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/programming/sort/defaultcs.aspx)

[RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/controls.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use THis code for Sorting........

```
 protected void RadgvData_SortCommand(object sender, GridSortCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            GridTableView tableView = e.Item.OwnerTableView;
            e.Canceled = true;
            GridSortExpression expression = new GridSortExpression();
            expression.FieldName = e.SortExpression;
            if (tableView.SortExpressions.Count == 0 || tableView.SortExpressions[0].FieldName != e.SortExpression)
            {
                expression.SortOrder = GridSortOrder.Descending;
            }
            else if (tableView.SortExpressions[0].SortOrder == GridSortOrder.Descending)
            {
                expression.SortOrder = GridSortOrder.Ascending;
            }
            else if (tableView.SortExpressions[0].SortOrder == GridSortOrder.Ascending)
            {
                expression.SortOrder = GridSortOrder.Descending;
            }

            tableView.SortExpressions.AddSortExpression(expression);
            RadgvData.Rebind();

        }
```